# Incorrect line when using Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, charts, antd

So I am making a chart using [Ant Design](https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/dual-axes/dual-line#dual-line) that display the Revenue and Forecast for the current year. My data looks like this:

```
[
{
    "Month": "January",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "February",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "March",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "April",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "May",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "June",
    "Revenue": 162.065,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "July",
    "Revenue": 1191.839,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "August",
    "Revenue": 1265.07,
    "Forecast": 0
},
{
    "Month": "September",
    "Revenue": 228.957,
    "Forecast": 228.957
},
{
    "Month": "October",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 114
},
{
    "Month": "November",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 171
},
{
    "Month": "December",
    "Revenue": 0,
    "Forecast": 142
}
]
```

I retrieve the data and send it to the dual axis chart and it gets plotted correctly..mostly. At the point where the Revenue and Forecast should intersect, they are wide apart with the Forecast being plotted incorrectly for that point only. Here is a pic to understand it better:
[image]
Why is this happening?
Here is my config component:

```
const config = {
data:[data2, data2],
xField: 'Month',
yField: ['Revenue', 'Forecast'],
geometryOptions: [
  {
    geometry: 'line',
    color: '#5B8FF9',
  },
  {
    geometry: 'line',
    color: '#FF0000',
  },
],
  };
```

Comment: Can you  show us how you config the component?

Comment: No clue how I forgot to add that. The question has been edited to include the config component.

Comment: It's okay, the funny thing is the chart is right . the problem is that there are two different y-axes. one is for Revenue (on the left of the chart) and the other is for Forecast (on the right of the chart). So basically it's correct. The reason for this is some times the maximum and the minimums of the two fields are not the same and because the designer wanted to show them both clearly and easily.
https://codesandbox.io/s/8zd69i?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by having the Revenue and Forecast be the same up until the intersection point.